# Tech differences between chrome and firefox packages apps & other html5 apps in blackberry,tizen

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome-app, tizen

Need to understand what are the basic technical differences between chrome and firefox packages apps & other html5 apps in blackberry,tizen.

All of them support apps in Html,Css,Js but where and how are they technically different
1.Can One app created for one platform be used for another without changes
2.If they cannot be used across then how easily can they be migrated
3.Are the differences only in manifest and main browser/os specific

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy answer for this one. You'd have to probably study each platform's api layer and then do a comparison. Start with chrome.* and then research all the other platforms. If you do end up doing this, please publish your results as I'm sure many future HTML5 app developers would love to read your findings!

Comment: I would love to see such a comparison

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 type of web apps.

1. Hosted Apps : It can be publicly accessible Web server, just like any other website.
2. Packaged Apps : It can be packaged sucg as a zip,wgt and so on, instead of hosting it on a web server. The apps file extension is depends on the plaform. (chrome, firefox, bbx, tizen...)

Both kinds of Web Apps are support all of HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and so on. 
One difference from a hosted app is that, a packaged app must specify a platform dependant metadata such as mainfest file. And there are different device apis. For example, firefox os provides their own web api for firefox app. Tizen also provides their own web device api for tizen application.

If one application is only standard API (HTML5), then all web platform supports it (Pacakaing may be differnet.). But if application also use non-standard api(like device api which is mentioned above), it couldn't reuse.